# Is there a way to create a loop which while only stop if specific strings are entered?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is make a loop which prompts the user for information and will only stop if certain strings are entered. Specifically, I want it only to accept certain letters, both upper and lowercase. Here's what I have so far:

```
 do
 {
  salesP = prompt("Enter the initial of the first name of the salesperson: ", "");
 }while (salesP != "C" || salesP != "c")
```

Basically the while part is completely wrong and I know it. I've tried everything I can think of, and the best I can do is get it to accept a single variable. I also need it to accept d, x, and m, both cases.

Comment: The `||` should be `&&` but seriously, please don't do this. Users hate it when you nag them with unstoppable prompts.

Comment: If you must do this, give them an option to quit (such as entering the letter `Q` or something).

Comment: Thanks kijin. I'm new to programming and this is just a lab. I don't need 2 do this but I want to go the extra mile. Could you explain to me why I use && instead of ||? I would've thought && would only work if all each individual variable was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is almost correct. You simply use the incorrect boolean operator in your while statement. You're using OR (`||`) where you should use AND (`&&`).

So:

```
 do
 {
  salesP = prompt("Enter the initial of the first name of the salesperson: ", "");
 }while (salesP != "C" && salesP != "c")
```

Comment: Why do I have to use AND though?

Comment: Well, you want to keep asking him the question until the user enters either `C` or `c`; keep prompting while he doesn't answer `C` and he doesn't answer `c`. This might help, perhaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws The condition is equivalent to `while(!(salesP == "C" || salesP == "c"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1
Permanent loop with an if statement, can use multiple if statements or other control structures to check for when to break.

```
while 1:
   if(raw_input('Enter some data please:') == specialString):
      break
```

Option 2
Part of loop

```
tempstring = ""
while (tempstring != specialString):
    tempstring = raw_input('Enter some data please:')
```

Option 3:
Recursion

```
def dataEntry(a,b,c):
    #data validation statements that fail on first iteration
    #statements to prompt user about data
    dataentry(a,b,c)
```

As far as how to check for the right string, I would recommend regular expressions.  Googling for "regex" examples is much better than me trying to explain it.

Comment: +1 for the regular expression comment. I would definitely use a regular expression for this and also avoid prompting the user on every keypress as well. Nothing as irritating as that!!

Comment: Thanks for all the info mvrak. It's too complicated for me at this point but I'm definitely going to look over it all.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to play with that if you are new you should become REALLY familiar with when doing string comparison is to eliminate case from the equation completely:

```
do
 {
  salesP = prompt("Enter the initial of the first name of the salesperson: ", "");
 }while (salesP.toLowerCase() != 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

just another approach

```
function promptSalesP(){
var _salesP = prompt("Enter the initial of the first name of the salesperson: ", "");
if(_salesP.toLowerCase() == "c")
return _salesP;
else
return promptSalesP(); 
}

var salesP = promptSalesP();
```

Comment: I don't like the recursive approach, personally. Too easy to stack overflow and crash. But to each his own.

Comment: "just another approach" And, looping could cause memory leak too in  js, refer http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index.shtml